# SSIS how to fail package on parallel step failure?

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to stop SSIS package from running with a failure error if one of the parallel tasks in a package fails? Now if parallel task fails other tasks stil execute. Take a look at the picture. It runs despite of putting on 'True' on FailPackageOnFailure and FailParentOnFailure in the task Properties.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would put the parallel tasks in a Sequence Container and flow from "1 Check Data" to the container then to "7 Reload"

[image: Sequence Container solution]

If any of the tasks in the Sequence Container fail, the entire container will fail and execution will not move on the the Final task (unless specified to continue even if errors)